# React native (latest) debugger not working in Visual Studio on Mac

Tags: react-native, visual-studio, visual-studio-code, expo, vscode-debugger

I've spent the past four days trying to get this to work. On the latest React Native / Expo / React Native Tools v1.12.1 on a fully updated Mac I cannot get the debugger to work, despite having followed every step I can find.

I have it to the point where the debug console says

```
Attaching to the application
Starting debugger app worker.
Established a connection with the Proxy (Packager) to the React Native application
```

But while no error is generated it doesn't want to step through breakpoints or even recognise errors when I use the default "Attach to packager" option.

MacOS Ventura 13.6.1, VS code version 1.79.

I can get the web debugger working but it's not ideal to have to drop out of the development environment and rebuild. Also when I try to create breakpoints in the web/chrome debugger it steps through to the depths of the node_modules folder rather than sticking with the app.js file.

Package.json

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo/webpack-config": "^19.0.0",
    "expo": "~49.0.15",
    "expo-dev-client": "~2.4.12",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.6.0",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.72.6",
    "react-native-web": "~0.19.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

metro.config.js (had to manually generate this, expo is no longer using metro bundler but the debugger kept demanding it)

```
// Learn more https://docs.expo.io/guides/customizing-metro
const { getDefaultConfig } = require('expo/metro-config');

/** @type {import('expo/metro-config').MetroConfig} */
const config = getDefaultConfig(__dirname);

module.exports = config;
```

Launch.json

```
{
  // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
  // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
  // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Attach to packager IP",
      "request": "attach",
      "type": "reactnative",
      "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
      "address": "192.168.1.2"
    },
    {
      "name": "Attach to packager",
      "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
      "type": "reactnative",
      "request": "attach"
    }
  ]
}
```